# Laravel Input::all() fetching one row only

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a form with a table example

Name | Review | Rating | Status

This table may have multiple rows and only Status is editable which is a dropdown field

I am able to show all the data, But when I save using code below, I notice that dd is only showing one row. When I save , one row is saved and then an error is displayed. 
Error:

> ErrorException in DashBoardController.php line 432: Creating default
>   object from empty value

where line number 432 is : `$approved_reviews->approved= $status1`

Below is my code snippet. Please help.

```
$approve_reviews = Input::except('_token');          

foreach ($approve_reviews as $review_id) {
    $approved_reviews = dealer_reviews::where('id',$review_id )->first();
    $status1 = Input::get('status');
    $approved_reviews->approved= $status1;

    $approved_reviews->save();
}
```

I have also tried `Input::all()`, but dd shows just one row.

My Form Code

```
@if(isset($pending_reviews))
       {!! Form::open(array('action' => array('DashBoardController@ApproveReviews' ), 'class'=>'form','files' => true,'data-toggle' => 'validator' ,'id'=>'edit_form')) !!}
       <div class="table-responsive">
         <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr class="danger">
              <td>
               <p style="font-weight:500;font-size:1.0em;"> Dealership Name </p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p style="font-weight:500;"> Review </p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p style="font-weight:500;"> Rating</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p style="font-weight:500;"> Suggestion</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p style="font-weight:500;"> Status </p>
              </td>
            <tr>

          </thead>

                  @foreach($pending_reviews as $p_review)
          <tr class="active">
              <td>
               <p style="font-weight:500;font-size:1.0em;"> {{$p_review-> dealership_name}} </p>
               <input type="hidden" value={{$p_review-> id}} name="review_id">

              </td>
              <td>
                <p style="font-weight:500;font-size:1.0em;"> {{$p_review-> review}} </p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p style="font-weight:500;font-size:1.0em;"> {{$p_review-> rating}} </p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p style="font-weight:500;font-size:1.0em;"> {{$p_review-> suggestions}} </p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p style="font-weight:500;font-size:1.0em;"> 
                 <select name="status">
            <option value="0">Pending</option>
             <option value="1">Approve</option>

        </select> 
                 </p>
              </td>

            <tr>
               @endforeach

         </table>
      </div>

       <input  type='submit' class="btn btn-success" name='Save' value='Submit' />
        {!! Form::close() !!}
        @else
        <h3> No Pending Reviews </h3>
        @endif
```

Comment: share your html code please.

Comment: Please share the form code

Comment: Won't fix your problem, but `dealer_reviews::where('id',$review_id )->first();` could be `dealer_reviews::find($review_id);`

Comment: I have added my form code. Please suggest what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Is it saving last row in your form?

Comment: Yes it is saving the last row. Also I tried to add {{id}} as name parameter to Input type="hidden" to uniquely identify the ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note you are given same name for all the inputs.
You have to change this line.

```
<input type="hidden" value={{$p_review-> id}} name="review_id">
```

By concatenating id to the name.
Inside your foreach loop increase the id and assign it to the name
along with "review_id".

```
<input type="hidden" value={{$p_review-> id}} name="review_id_{{$i}}">

foreach ($approve_reviews as $review_id) {
    $new_id = explode("_ ",$review_id);
    $approved_reviews =dealer_reviews::where('id',$new_id[0])->first();
    $status1 = Input::get('status');
    $approved_reviews->approved= $status1;

    $approved_reviews->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, it is now fetching all the rows. In this case , What do I put in the where clause $approve_reviews = Input::all();          
              
              foreach ($approve_reviews as $reviews) {
              $reviews_approved = dealer_reviews::where('id',??? )->first();
              $status1 = Input::get('status');
              $reviews_approved->approved= $status1;
              $reviews_approved->save();
                    
             }

Comment: Any inputs ? please

Comment: Now you are getting input with review_id and id that you concatenate combine with underscore.You need to split $review_id inside the foreach loop. $new_id = explode("_ ",$review_id) . In the where clause use $new_id[0] instead of $review_id

Comment: No it did not. I think the foreach should be able to loop through all the review_ids. That isn't happening. Please try it and update if possible.

Comment: I added the changes for foreach loop.  Please check edited answer

Answer (score 0):

That error means that `$approved_reviews` is not an object at that point. In your case, that means that no record was found with an id matching `$review_id`, which seems likely since this line suggests not all your inputs are IDs:

```
$status1 = Input::get('status');
```

You probably need to shift your logic around a bit, but I can't offer any more detail than that without seeing a sample of your input.

Comment: I have added my form code. Please suggest what I am doing wrong here